# SQL many to many relation: create N random records in relations table

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

There are tree tables:

```
Table1
------------------
| Id | CreatedBy |
------------------

Table2
------------------
| Id | CreatedBy |
------------------

Table3 (table to store relations between Table1 and Table2)
-----------------------
| table1Id | table2Id |
-----------------------
```

I have many records with different creators in tables 1 and 2. What I need is to **create relations between all records in table 1 and N random records in table2** (of course for same creator).

What I have tried already:

- create select with inner join that will create relation records

> ```
> INSERT INTO Table3
> SELECT t1.Id, t2.Id FROM Table1 t1
> INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP(10) Id, CreatedBy FROM Table2 ORDER BY NEWID()) AS t2
> ON t1.CreateBy = t2.CreatedBy
> ```

the problem here that subquery can return top 10 records created by other creators and after ON t1.CreateBy = t2.CreatedBy we will get empty result.

- write this query without join (few select statements but without success).

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to do? You are pulling random records from table 2 to match records in table1... why? Typically when you have a many to many relationship between tables, you want to create a bridge entity to change that relationship to many to 1.

Comment: Are you just generating some test data so you have some data to work with? I hope so, otherwise this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @DanK: I have separate entities in table1 and table2 but user can relate them in many to many way. For test purpose I generated entities in tables 1 and 2, now I wanna create relation between them. So I want to create relations for each entity in table1 and few random entites in table2.

Comment: N Records for each user or N records total?  I'm guessing user based on this... and result could be N or < N because user may not have N records?

Comment: @Sean Lange: yes, I am generating test data, you are right.

Comment: @xQbert: relation between ALL records from table1 and N records from table2. So if there 100 rows in table1 and N is 10, 1000 have to be created (if there are enough rows in table2)

Comment: So why are you only creating some of the data? Why not just create all of the details? SELECT t1.Id, t2.Id 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.CreateBy = t2.CreatedBy

Comment: @Sean Lange I can create relations between all records, it is not a problem. The question is how can I relate only few random entities if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to only create part of the data? This is quite a bizarre requirement. Something like this maybe?

```
with MyCTE as
(
    SELECT t1.Id as ID1, t2.Id as ID2, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.CreateBy order by (select newid())) as RowNum
    FROM Table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.CreateBy = t2.CreatedBy
)

insert Table3
select ID1, ID2
from MyCTE
where RowNum <= 10
```

Comment: I generate data for test purpose, so nothing strange:) This one works great, but I always get first 10 rows from table2, they are not randomized.

Comment: Seems strange to me that you only generate some of the relational data but whatever. The code here will return those rows in a random order each time it is run. I don't know what else I can do to help here.

Comment: I found what was wrong in the script. Next statement should be used partition by t1.CreatedBy order by newid() instead of partition by t1.CreateBy order by (select newid()).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
Declare @Query Nvarchar(Max)
Declare @Num int=10
Set @Query='
Select a.Id,b.Id 
From Table1 a
Inner join (
    Select top '+ltrim(Rtrim(Str(@Num)))+' t.Id,t.CreatedBy 
    From Table2 t order by newid()) as b
    On (a.CreatedBy=b.CreatedBy)'
Exec sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: I tried cross join as well. But how can I modify this script to select N random rows from Table2?

Comment: By this way you only have to set de @Num

Comment: You wrote same code as I mentioned in question description, I tried this one. Few problems here: 1. records are not randomized. 2. Subquery can return only records that were created by another creator.